# Solr - How to import my own transformer to solr-data-config.xml?

Tags: java, xml, solr

I'm a new programmer for Solr and Java, I am facing some problems while using the custom transformer. I write a custom transformer to format my data from MySQL, like this:

```java
package foo;

import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.Context;
import org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.Transformer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TempleteTransformer extends Transformer{

    @Override
    public Object transformRow(Map<String, Object> map, Context context) {
        List<Map<String,String>> fieldlist = context.getAllEntityFields();
        for (Map<String,String> field : fieldlist){
            String trim = field.get("trim");
            if ("true".equals(trim)){
                String columnName = field.get("column");
                String value = String.valueOf(map.get(columnName));
                JSONArray ja = JSONArray.fromObject(value);
                List sl = JSONArray.toList(ja);
                List<String> strlist = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < sl.size(); i++){
                    strlist.add((String) sl.get(i));
                }
                map.put(columnName,strlist);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

}
```

I can package this project as a jar file, but where should I put this jar?

And how I import it in `solr-data-config.xml`?

I have read the official doc but it doesn't say how to use.

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

1. This is the preferred way: put it anywhere you like (ie YOURFULLPATH, an then in solrconfig.xml, you include it like this:

   ```
   <lib dir="YOURFULLPATH" regex=".*\.jar" />
   ```

   If you look at the sample solrconfig.xml you will see there are different variations for using , most of them will work.
2. if by any chance the above does not work, and you don't feel like troubleshooting, you can just drop your jar in apache-solr\server\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\ and it should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your `server/solr/solr.xml` file the entry `<str name='sharedLib'>` and the restart Solr.

For example:

```xml
<solr>

  <str name='sharedLib'>/opt/shared-lib</str>

  <solrcloud>

    <str name="host">${host:}</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8983}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>

    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>

    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:30000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateSoTimeout">${distribUpdateSoTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateConnTimeout">${distribUpdateConnTimeout:60000}</int>
    <str name="zkCredentialsProvider">${zkCredentialsProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.DefaultZkCredentialsProvider}</str>
    <str name="zkACLProvider">${zkACLProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.DefaultZkACLProvider}</str>

  </solrcloud>

  <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
    class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:60000}</int>
  </shardHandlerFactory>

</solr>
```

Into the directory `/opt/shared-lib` place the jar files you need.

Those jar files will be shared across all your cores.

For Solr versions older than 5.x the file `solr.xml` is located in the `$SOLR_HOME` env var or configured through the java property `-Dsolr.solr.home`.